# How to set filter by object in tableview without search bar?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, uitableview, filter

I have a tableview and I want to add a button that will filter the data by the given option. For example, I want to display only data that contains a "Attending" in the table.
Here is my code:

```
 func filterBy(){
    let addEvent = UIAlertController(title: "Sort by:", message: "Sort guests", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let subview = (addEvent.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first!)! as UIView
    let shapes = UIView()
    shapes.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    shapes.layer.borderWidth = 5
    shapes.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9843137255, green: 0.8196078431, blue: 0.8509803922, alpha: 1)
    subview.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843137, green: 0.9333333333, blue: 0.9176470588, alpha: 1)
    subview.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9843137255, green: 0.8196078431, blue: 0.8509803922, alpha: 1)
    addEvent.view.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4431372549, green: 0.4431372549, blue: 0.4431372549, alpha: 1)
    
    let addSortAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Attending", style: .default) { (action) in
        let sortedBy: () = self.guestsList.sort(by: { $0.attendingStatus ?? "" > $1.attendingStatus ?? ""})
       print(sortedBy)
        self.guestsTableView.reloadData()
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default)
    addEvent.addAction(addSortAction)
    addEvent.addAction(cancelAction)
    present(addEvent, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return guestsList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "guestCell", for: indexPath) as! GuestTableViewCell
    let guest: GuestModel
    guest = guestsList[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.guestNameLabel.text = guest.guestName! + " " + guest.guestFamilyName!
    cell.attendingLabel.text = guest.attendingStatus
    cell.menuLabel.text = guest.menuStatus
    cell.ageLabel.text = guest.ageStatus
    cell.tableLabel.text = guest.tableNo
    
    return cell
}
```

The model:

```
class GuestModel {
    
    var guestName: String?
    var attendingStatus: String?
    var menuStatus: String?
    var ageStatus: String?
    var tableNo: String?
    var id: String?
    var guestFamilyName: String?
    var guestPhoneNumber: String?
    var guestEmail: String?
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your table view data source and delegate methods? And your list item model class? I don't understand why you are creating a dialog to sort your values while you need to filter them.

Comment: @luca_999 I was trying first to sort, but now I need to filter values, and because I'm new in swift I don't know how to filter them.

Comment: Ok, still, Can you post your table view data source and delegate methods? And your list item model class?

Comment: @luca_999 I edited the question. There is data source and delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want you could use three global variables

1. The full list that you initialize at the beginning (guestsList)
2. The filtered list, used as table view data source (filteredGuestsList)
3. The searched string, which applies the filter to the list (in my case a considered that you'll apply a filter to the `guestName` property)

The `filterBy` method needs only to update the searched value, and needs to be called everytime you want to clear or update the searched value.

```
private var guestsList = [GuestModel]() {
    didSet {
        filteredGuestsList = guestsList
    }
}
private var filteredGuestsList = [GuestModel]() {
    didSet {
        guestsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
private var search = "" {
    didSet {
        filteredGuestsList = search != "" ? guestsList.filter {
            $0.guestName.uppercased().contains(searchText.uppercased())
        } : guestsList
    }
}

func filterBy(_ text: String) {
    search = text
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredGuestsList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "guestCell", for: indexPath) as! GuestTableViewCell
    let guest = filteredGuestsList[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.guestNameLabel.text = guest.guestName! + " " + guest.guestFamilyName!
    cell.attendingLabel.text = guest.attendingStatus
    cell.menuLabel.text = guest.menuStatus
    cell.ageLabel.text = guest.ageStatus
    cell.tableLabel.text = guest.tableNo
    
    return cell
}
```